# React Native Redux State Simply Not Working (Undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.all_subjects.current').

Index.js

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import subjectsReducer from './reducers/subjectsReducer';
import Home from "./screens/home";
import Subjects from "./screens/subjects";

const store = createStore(subjectsReducer);
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        <Stack.Screen
                            name="Home"
                            component={Home}
                        />
                        <Stack.Screen
                            name="Subjects"
                            component={Subjects}
                        />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
 
export default App;
```

subjectsReducers.js

```
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    current: [],
    all_subjects: [
        'Literature',
        'Speech',
        'Writing',
        'Algebra',
        'Geometry',
        'Statistics',
        'Chemisrty',
        'Biology',
        'Physics',
        'Economics',
        'Geography',
        'History',
    ],
};

const subjectsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SELECT_SUBJECT':
        
            // copy the state 
            const { current,  all_subjects,} = state;
    
            //remove a subject from the all_subjects array
            
            const addedSubject = all_subjects.splice(action.payload, 1);
    
            // put subject in current array
            current.push(addedSubject);
    
            // update the redux state to reflect the change
            const newState = { current, all_subjects };
            
            //return new state
            return newState;
    
        default:
            return state
        }
  };
  

export default combineReducers({
    subjects: subjectsReducer
});
```

subjectsActions.js

```
export const addSubject = subjectsIndex => (
    {
        type: 'SELECT_SUBJECT',
        payload: subjectsIndex,
    }
);
```

Subjects.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Subjects extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Select Subjects Below!</Text>
            {this.props.subjects.all_subjects.map((subject, index) => (
                <Button
                    key={ subject }
                    title={ `Add ${ subject }` }
                    onPress={() =>
                    this.props.addSubject(index)
                    }
                />
            ))}
            <Button
                title="Back to home"
                onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                }
            />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

// const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
//     const { subjects } = state
//     return { subjects }
// };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    subjects: state.subjects
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Subjects);
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>You have { this.props.all_subjects.current.length } subjects.</Text>
            <Button
            title="Select more subjects"
            onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Subjects')
            }
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    text:{
        color: '#888',
        fontSize: 18
    },
    input: {
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
        borderColor: '#7a42f4',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    submitButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
    },
    submitButtonText:{
        color: 'white'
    }
});

// const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
//   const { subjects } = state
//   return { subjects }
// };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    subjects: state.subjects
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Home);
```

I am new to react native.  I have searched everywhere for a solution for this issue, but I can’t seem to get anywhere.  I have used redux in standard react, but I don’t know why this isn’t working.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with:
`this.props.subjects && this.props.subjects.all_subjects....`

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I also tried doing just this.props.all_subjects.length.  I am almost certain the state is not being "transferred" over to home.js

Comment: Oh jeez, silly mistake on my part.  Wasted a few hours on this.

Comment: Glad you worked out :D